# How to add tags to an app in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm wondering if there are any built-in tools in Android Studio for tags like the ones we have when posting a question here on StackOverFlow?

I'm new to Android and haven't seen any provided views like it.

Or are there any sample codes to accomplish this?

What I want as results are:

1. users can type in some letters or key words (one or two) and there will be choices provided show up and the users can choose from those.
2. if there is no tag the user want to choose, then he/she can create one by just choosing nothing and type in "," as separation, then this will be a new tag stored for later users.
3. tags are separated by ",", and each will be in a rectangle container (like on stackOverFlow or other sites)and users can have up to e.g. 5 tags.

This should be done in one activity.

Thanks for any solutions and advice.